# Altova Mapforce date mapping field is not working

Tags: altova

I'm mapping 2 mysql databases. In DB1 one of the field is a date field. The default value for the field is '0000-00-00'. When excecution I get this error:

Conversion to date failed for '0000-00-00'

I mapping to a string field in DB2. But it's seems the problem occurs before it's trying to insert/update.

Comment: You need to format the date as per the alotva format or create the date function into altova map force where you map your year,month and day with alotva value.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you have any example how to make the date function into map force? It's seems to do the date check before it "enters" the mapping.

Comment: This is page for discussion not providing source code. You need to read altova mapforce support book or ask to altova mapforce support center